# Problems to represent a Tree using PrimeNG

Tags: html, angular, tree, primeng

I have a question about representing a tree with PrimeNG. I would like to test the representation of the tree before filling it with data from a JSON file. So I tried the following. Firsteval I wrote the HTML file, where my tree shoud be represented. Thats shown in the following code.

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<p-tree [value]="files" selectionMode="single" layout="horizontal"></p-tree>
```

After that, I did the following in the component. I wrote a method where the TreeNode-Array `files` is filled with some short Input data. After that, I assigned files to the value of this function. This is shown in the following code:

```
files: TreeNode[] = this.bla();

bla(): TreeNode[]{

    let TN1: TreeNode = {};
    let TN2: TreeNode = {};
    let TN3: TreeNode = {};
    let TN4: TreeNode = {};

    console.log('in bla');

    TN1.data='TN1';
    TN1.label='TN1';
    TN2.data='TN2';
    TN2.label='TN2';
    TN3.data='TN3';
    TN3.label='TN3';
    TN4.data='TN4';
    TN4.label='TN4';
    TN1.children = [TN3];
    TN2.children = [TN4];
    return [TN1,TN2,TN3,TN4];
}
```

In my opinion, that's all I should do for testing. I got no Errors or something like that, but the tree is not shown... I hope that anyone can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems to work in this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-tfvwyj?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: I am getting correct output for the code snippet you given. May be you were annoyed because you returned four treenode **(TN1, TN2, TN3, TN4)** but it shows always the first one. The reason is you are using a horizontal layout. In horizontal layout tree, you have to set only one root element then you can expand the leafs as per your requirement and the root element will be with in a treenode array.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, I just add the TreeModule into the file *.module.ts.
Import and added to NgModule

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).